# Google storage bucket stats using Cloud Storage Client Libraries

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I have a web application that creates/deletes buckets, uploads/downloads objects from google storage and I am successfully using Google Apis Storage v1 and v1.Data in C#.

I would like to know if there is a way to find out how much space a bucket has used using the Google Apis.  I was thinking something like StorageClient.GetBucket would return this information but it doesn't seem to.

All the help documentation seems to point to the gsutil but I can't use that as this is for a web application.
So to clarify I am using Cloud Storage Client Libraries

I want to be able to look at any given moment how much space has been used for a particular bucket, using the Google.Storage.Apis (which isn't the XML API or JSON API)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up bucket logging per [Bucket Logging Doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs), which will generate a file once a day with the total size (in bytes) of the buckets you defined.

And you've created a feature request as [FR/37237171](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37237171) at the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks, this isn't quite what I require.  I've edited my original post just to clarify

Comment: The problem is that there is no such Google.Storage.Apis available at the moment for you to see the usage of a given bucket...

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick response.  Do you know if this will be added into the Api in the future?

Comment: I'm uncertain at the moment, but I strongly suggest you can make a feature request per instructions at https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests so that you'll have more info and updates from the request there :)